# How do I define a function in PHP for use by two different classes?

Tags: php

I have two PHP classes, and want to do something like this:

```
class Class1
{
    $x=3;
    coolFunction($x);
    }

class Class2
{
    $y = 7;
    coolFunction($y);
    }
```

I tried doing:

```
public function coolFunction($z)
{
    $youGetTheIdea = 10;
    return $z + $youGetTheIdea;
    }
```

But PHP didn't like that, and I am at a loss at this point. How can I make the function accessible to both classes, or is there a way to do something similar? I'm coming from a Python background, so anything you can do to shed light on my understanding of PHP would be awesome.

Comment: Just define an ordinary function, not a method.

Comment: Yes, an ordinary function is all I need. I used the function declaration outside of the scope of both classes, by the way.

Comment: Look into “traits”: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [trait](http://php.net/trait).

```
trait TraitCoolFunction {
    private function coolFunction($z) {
        $youGettheIdea = 10;
        return $z + $youGetTheIdea;
    }
}
```

To use:

```
class Class1 {
    use TraitCoolFunction;
    /* other stuff here */
}
```

Requires PHP 5.4 or newer.

Comment: When would you do it this way, if you can think of a clear example?

Comment: When you only want the function to exist in certain classes rather than everywhere. When you want to separate your functions into organised files. For a number of other reasons that are case-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can only specify `public` or `private` for class methods. Ordinary functions outside classes are defined with just `function`:

```
function coolFunction($z)
{
    $youGetTheIdea = 10;
    return $z + $youGetTheIdea;
}
```